# logical python comparison, evaluates False when it should be true

Tags: python

Why does the following evaluates to False in Python?

```
6==(5 or 6)
False

'b'==('a' or 'b')
False
```

Comment: Why do you think it should be true? It seems you want to do `6 in (5, 6)` but do not know the correct syntax and you blame it on the language.

Comment: @VincentSavard: You are right. I for once, started thinking in mathematical sense.

Answer (score 2):

The first expression evaluates `(5 or 6)` first, which evaluates to `5` because `5` is truthy. `5` is NOT equal to `6` so it returns `False`.

The second expression evaluates `('a' or 'b')` first, which evaluates to `'a'` for the same reason as above. `'a'` is NOT equal to `'b'` so it returns `False`.

A good example to explain this would be to try to put a falsey value as the first part of the or expression like `6 == ([ ] or 6)` or `6 == (None or 6)`. Both of these will return true because the or statement will evaluate to the truthy value (in each case it is `6`).

There are a couple of ways to create the statement I think you want. The first would be to use `in` like `6 in (6,5)`. The second way would be to expand your boolean expression to read like this `(6 == 5) or (6 == 6)`. Both of these will return `True`.

Comment: Actually, `5 or 6` evaluates to `5 `.

Comment: The problem of this website is that people usually have the fury of answering just to receive points.  Anyway, I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

The condition within parentheses is evaluated first. So

```
6==(5 or 6)
```

evaluates to

```
6==(5) # since 5 != 0 (True), the second operand is not evaluated
```

which is `False`. Same goes for the second one. (`'a' != None`)

Comment: I think that here the question is asking why `5 or 6` evaluates to `5`. Of course the rest is superfluous and does not need an answer at all.

Comment: @nbro: This answers my question. I forgot for a moment that right side is evaluated first.

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Then, I must be honest, I needed to downvote your question, because your problem is really basic and easy to solve if you have a minimal programming experience (with any language that I know, and I know a few).

Comment: @nbro: Ya, I feel pretty stupid now after asking this question. I knew this long time ago.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
>>>6 == (6 or 5)
True
```

What's going on? Try:

```
>>5 or 6
5
```

I'm not totally sure why "5 or 6" evaluates to 5, but I would just try writing that expression differently.

Comment: It takes the first truthy value in the or expression, so if you did `None or 5` or `[ ] or 5` you would get `5` as well

Comment: The `or` operator is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

Answer (score -1):

But there is a caveat:

```
>> 5 == (0 or 5)
True
```

Because 0 is not truth-worthy, hence the bracket result in 5.